# Foswiki and LDAP authentication

Tags: apache, ldap, foswiki

I have a problem with connecting foswiki to ldap. I want to authenticate users against LDAP directory (as it is stated in the requirements of school seminar work ). But it doesn't work. When I try to login with my name already saved in LDAP, it just writes "Oops: we could not recognize you. Try again or reset your password.". I will be thankful for any help and I will provide any further information necessary.

Foswiki config: http://pastebin.com/NRx4V9Ck

I am trying to login with name MarianBaca and here is the output of 
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost -b dc=bis01,dc=vse,dc=cz -x '(givenName=Marian)'

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=bis01,dc=vse,dc=cz> with scope subtree
# filter: (givenName=Marian)
# requesting: ALL
#

# MarianBaca, bis01.vse.cz
dn: cn=MarianBaca,dc=bis01,dc=vse,dc=cz
cn: MarianBaca
givenName: Marian
gidNumber: 500
sn: Baca
loginShell: /bin/sh
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
uidNumber: 1000
uid: MarianBaca
homeDirectory: /home/MarianBaca

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Output of /etc/ldap/ldap.conf

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=bis01,dc=vse, dc=cz
URI     ldap://bis01.vse.cz

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your pasted foswiki configuration has been removed, I will try to answer to my best knowledge.

- I am assuming you are using LdapContrib
- Ensure your UserMappingManager is set to Foswiki::Users::LdapUserMapping.
- Ensure your PasswordManager is set to something sensible, i.e. Foswiki::Users::LdapPasswduser